# Combination Sum II time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity, backtracking

I've used backtracking to solve this LeetCode problem - [Combination Sum II](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-ii/description/)

What would be the worst-case time complexity for below solution? How do we approach such backtracking problems for their time complexity analysis?

From my analysis, each element in `candidates` array can be either included or excluded. Hence, time complexity should become `O(2^n)`.

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum2(int[] candidates, int target) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean[] used = new boolean[candidates.length];

        // Sort array to avoid duplicate combinations
        Arrays.sort(candidates);

        getCombos(candidates, target, result, used, new ArrayList<>(), 0, 0);

        return result;
    }

    public void getCombos(int[] candidates, int target, List<List<Integer>> result, boolean[] used, List<Integer> curr, int sum, int index) {
        if(sum == target) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));
            return;
        }

        for(int i = index; i < candidates.length; i++) {
            // If duplicate is found, then include only if previous occurrence is chosen
            if(i > 0 && candidates[i] == candidates[i - 1] && !used[i - 1]) {
                continue;
            }
            // Add current to combo
            used[i] = true;
            curr.add(candidates[i]);

            // Generate combinations using curr
            if(sum + candidates[i] <= target)
                getCombos(candidates, target, result, used, curr, sum + candidates[i], i + 1);

            // Remove current for next combination
            used[i] = false;
            curr.remove(curr.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post what you *think* the answer is and why you think that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking only at `candidates`, there are `2^n` combinations. The backtracking needs to iterate through them all. Then for each combinations, it needs to be copied to a new list at the end, so there's an extra factor of `n`, for a total time complexity of `O(n*2^n)`.

This would not run in time though as `2^100` is huge. Instead, the time complexity is better expressed in terms of `target`. The constraint that `target` is small limits the time based on the [Partition Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). So the time complexity is `O(n*p(target))`.